# How to convert HH:MM:SS to time.time() object in Python

Tags: python, arrays, string, datetime, time

I need to convert `HH:MM:SS` format to `time.time()` object. Is there any way to do it?

Here's my `HH:MM:SS` format time:

```
a = '14:37:29'
```

I want to convert it to `time.time()` object such as:

```
a = 1600256249
```

Is this achievable? If it's not, what should I try? Hope you help.

Comment: Is a a string? If so you you can start looking over here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466345/converting-string-into-datetime

Comment: Please make sure you read all answers in the suggested duplicate. Your question might not be answered in the accepted answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get UNIX time, you need to add a date. For example, you could combine your time string with today's date:

```
from datetime import datetime, timezone

s = '14:37:29'
today = datetime.today() # 2020-09-16

# make a datetime object with today's date
dt = datetime.combine(today, datetime.strptime(s, '%H:%M:%S').time())

# make sure it's in UTC (optional)
dt = dt.replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc)

# get the timestamp
ts = dt.timestamp()
print(ts)
# 1600267049.0
```

You could also set other time zones with this approach using [dateutil](https://pypi.org/project/python-dateutil/) or [zoneinfo](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zoneinfo.html) (Python 3.9+).

Answer (score 1):

*Is this achievable?*

I would say no. `a = '14:37:29'` holds only hour-minute-second, whilst `time.time()` does return seconds since start of epoch i.e. you would also need to known day, month and year beside hour, minute, second, to create equivalent of what `time.time()` returns.